# Fragment Replace BottomNavigation Half Hide

Tags: xml, kotlin

when fragment replace some time bottom navigation bar half hide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2bsY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check in you XML file where you use BottomNavigationView and remove it. it's working fine

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```